# C Lang: Quick sorting 5 elements but doesn't sort 10 elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I am confused on why code only sorts 5 elements but not 10 elements. This method was described to me during my office visit with my professor. So I followed his instructions when I coded this. Can someone please help me fix this problem? My code works but it doesn't work on a bigger array. I know it is too late for someone to help before its due but I just want to understand what I had done in this code.

Thank You

```
/* Homework3.c
Qucksort arrays
Jared DaRocha
3/1/2020

 */


#include <stdio.h>// preprocessor 

int partition(int arr[], int first, int end);// function declaration

void quickSort(int arr[], int first, int end);// function declaration

int main(void)// beginning of main

{
    //Data
    int array[5];// creates an array of 5 elements
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); // calculates size of the array


    // prompt user to input data to input int the array
    printf("Enter 5 numbers to add in the array");
    // prompts user to input 10 numbers
    for(int i =0;i<size; i++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);// stores user-defined data into the array
    }


    // call the function to sort the array
    quickSort(array, 0, size -1);


    // prints array 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}


int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)// Function declaration
{
    //Data
    int partition = arr[low]; // partition number


        // infinite for loop
        for (;;)
        {
          // decrement high while partition is smaller than element of high
            while(partition <arr[high]) 
            {

              high--;


            }


            // if partition is greater than element of high, swap high with low element since low element is the pivot
            if(partition > arr[high]){
              int temp = arr[low];

              arr[low] = arr[high];
              arr[high] = temp;
              low++;

            }           
            // increment low while partition is greater than element of low
            while(partition > arr[low])
            {

              low++;

            }

            // swap low and next element in the right if  partition is less than element of low
            if(partition < arr[low])
            {
              int temp = arr[low];
              arr[low] = arr[low+1];
              arr[low+1] = temp;
            }

            // if low is same as high then  exit loop
            if(high == low)
            {
              break;
            }


    }


    return low;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int first, int end) // function definition
{
    if (first < end) 
    {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, first, end);
        quickSort(arr, first, (partitionIndex - 1));
        quickSort(arr, (partitionIndex+1 ), end);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Is this the code that is supposed to be able to sort 10 elements or is it the original 5 element version? It is not clear as it has references to both 5 and 10.

Comment: The shown code has `5` as magic number in more than one place. Please show the code you use for sorting 10. If this **is** the code which has trouble sorting any other number than 5 I am not surprised and will claim the answer.

Comment: I was testing it with 10 elements and I decided to test with 5 elements. I forgot to change the comments. I did little more testing and found out it only sorted odd numbers and didnt work with even numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you check the algorithm quicksort, you'll find how the array is divided into two slices that don't overlap, but also don't leave a single element hung around.  You do this, just between both slices, you leave a single element. You divide the array in two slices and one single array element that doesn't participate in the recursive calls to the other slices.... and that's incorrect.  What you know is that all elements of the inferior slice are less than the token, and the rest are greater than or equal than the token... but the point of division can be any element of the array subpart that corresponds.

By the way, the code or partition is completely incorrect.  You first select one element that will act as a token, you can select it as any element of the array or as the average value of all of them, it doesn't matter... you are not going to put it in the array.  then search from the end elements that are under the array, and search from the beginning elements that are over the token, once you have one such pair, switch them, but you exchange the found elements with the token, which not only doesn't do what is expected, but introduces copies of the token (and change its value) thing that will trash your array.

You are not searching for an array element... you are searching for a place (between to adjacent elements) where to divide your array, and the subarrays will be from beg, to pos-1, and from pos to end, (or from beg to pos, then from pos + 1 to end) but don't ignore the central element, because you know it belongs to an array, but it's not necessary the token.